# Validating and parsing phone number into 3 values using Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse phone numbers written in the "(222) 555-2333" format, i.e., a three-digit area code enclosed in parentheses followed by a seven-digit local number in three-hyphen-four digit format. It should also ignore all leading and trailing spaces, as well as any spaces that appear between the area code and local numbers. However, it should not accept any spaces in the area code (e.g., in '(222)') nor should it in the seven-digit local number.

This is what I have written so far. It's working for '(800) 121-2121' but failing for '  (333)  122-2222'. I tried adding \s in the beginning of the pattern but that hasn't help either. Any idea where I'm getting wrong?

```
import re
s = "   (333)   122-2222"
reg = re.compile(r'^\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})-(\d{4})$')
test = bool(re.match(reg,s))
if test:
   reg.search(s).groups() 
else:
   ValueError
```

Comment: Also, is there a way, I can handle spaces only when they come with a special character? In this case, (404) 555-1212 is fine but the regex need to reject 404 555-1212

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check for spaces at the start too,

```
import re
s = "   (333)   122-2222"
reg = re.compile(r'^\s*\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})-(\d{4})$')
test = bool(re.match(reg,s))
if test:
   reg.search(s).groups() 
else:
   ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i got your problem i think you should also search for spaces in between the codes.
just add some more \s* in between you will get it

```
import re
s = "   (333)   122-2222"
reg = re.compile(r'^\s*\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})\s*-\s*(\d{4})\s*$')
test = bool(re.match(reg,s))
if test:
   reg.search(s).groups() 
else:
   ValueError
```